# Covert XML batch file to TXT

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, txt

I have a batch of xml files i need to convert to text that I need to extract certain information from.

From the files I want to extract Title and and multiple names
I have attempted to use this ode:

```
tree = ET.parse(r"file_name")
root = tree.getroot()

for page in root.findall('page'):
    print("Titles: ", page.find('titles').txt)
    print("V_Name: ", page.find('v_name').txt)
```

I am not getting any result.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: share the xml and explain the expected output